# Как узнать уровень вложенности функции

Tags: c++, функции, логирование

Придумал интересную задачу.

Она заключается в том, чтобы в правильном виде выводить логи в функциях.
Приведу пример:

Этот макрос упростит нам жизнь, он просто выводит какие-то логи в консоль:

```
#define LOG_INFO(msg)\
  std::cout << msg << std::endl
```

Несколько пустых функций, в которых выводятся какие-то логи

```
void _A(){
  LOG_INFO("The function _A STARTED here");
  LOG_INFO("The function _A ENDED here");
}

void _B(){
  LOG_INFO("The function _B STARTED here");
  _A();
  LOG_INFO("The function _B ENDED here");
}

void _C(){
  LOG_INFO("The function _C STARTED here");
  _B();
  LOG_INFO("The function _C ENDED here");
}

int main(){
  _C();
}
```

Вывод будет таким:

```
The function _C STARTED here
The function _B STARTED here
The function _A STARTED here
The function _A ENDED here
The function _B ENDED here
The function _C ENDED here
```

А мне хотелось бы, чтобы автоматически, в зависимости от вложенности, перед логами были отступы, например:

```
The function _C STARTED here
....The function _B STARTED here
........The function _A STARTED here
........The function _A ENDED here
....The function _B ENDED here
The function _C ENDED here
```

Я не хочу передавать текущий уровень вложенности из функции в функцию, можно это как-то определить иначе?

Comment: Класс с соответствующим полем :)

Comment: можно сделать в логгера функцию "увеличить текущий уровень/уменьшить". А далее, используя RAII, маленький класс-обертку (в конструкторе вызывается увеличение, в деструкторе - уменьшение) и чуточку макросов для заворачивания этого в одну строку и вуаля, все работает

Comment: Нашел то, о чем написали в комментариях - https://habr.com/ru/post/148781/

Comment: Под винду я что-то подобное делал с использованием WinAPI функции `CaptureStackBackTrace` для "раскрутки" стека вызова. Пример кода пока не могу привести, нужно поискать тот проект на домашней машине. Под линь можно использовать `backtrace` с той же целью.  Из минусов: траблы с многопоточностью и необходимость держать отдельные ветки под каждую платформу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так не хотите?

```
class Logg
{
public:
    Logg(const char * f):f(f)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < lvl; ++i) cout << "    ";
        cout << "The function " << f << " STARTED here\n";
        lvl++;
    }
    ~Logg()
    {
        lvl--;
        for(int i = 0; i < lvl; ++i) cout << "    ";
        cout << "The function " << f << " ENDED here\n";
    }
private:
    string f;
    inline static int lvl = 0;
};

void C()
{
    Logg L(__FUNCTION__);
}


void B()
{
    Logg L(__FUNCTION__);
    C();
}

void A()
{
    Logg L(__FUNCTION__);
    B();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    A();
}
```

Comment: Только надо уточнить, что с многопоточностью и longjmp-ми сломается

Comment: @avp Конечно, сломается. Но longjmp вообще ломает саму идею конструктора-деструктора, нет? а с многопоточностью нужно располагать счетчик в памяти потока.

Comment: Да, longjmp много чего может  сломать, в более-менее нетривиальной с++ программе этого вообще не отследить

Comment: А зачем заводить string с выделением памяти, если можно просто сохранять переданный указатель?

Comment: @avp, а что за longjump'ы?

Comment: @Qwertiy Можно и не вводить, но тогда надо гарантировать его существование до конца. Да, при вызове `Logg L(__FUNCTION__);` это нормально и не важно, ну а если кому-то захочется его использовать для чего-либо иного?... Теряется универсальность, нет?

Comment: Да вроде не теряется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну, вполне можно придумать, как указатель становится невалидным или указывает на строку, отличную от исходной...

Comment: @Harry, можно потребовать использование только литеральных строк.

Comment: @Qwertiy А можно пример кода?

Comment: @Qwertiy, [man longjmp](https://linux.die.net/man/3/longjmp) крайнее средство для выхода из безнадежных ситуаций

Comment: @Harry, ну я думал про `#define WITH_LOG(hint) Logg L("" hint)`, но с ним `__FUNCTION__` тоже не работает :( Можно как-то починить? https://ideone.com/iHulLS

Comment: @Qwertiy Гм, а в VC++ вполне отработало...

Comment: @Harry, ну я ожидал, что макрос раскрывается в литерал, тогда должно работать, но на ideone почему-то не хочет ((

Answer (score -2):

Всё реализовано в библиотеке. Не надо использовать макросы кроме условной компиляции и инклюдов.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stacktrace
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location

Comment: Что-то я не вижу чтобы stacktrace отступы расставлял в выводе в логи. Топик стартер про автоматические отступы спрашивал, и Scoped объекты тут идеально подходят. А stacktrace нужен чтобы стек вызовов отобразить, а не для отступов

Comment: И что значит не надо использовать макросы? Их надо использовать с осторожностью, иногда они позволяют очень удобные штуки проворачивать.